# using SGD classifier in mahout

Tags: mahout

By following the donut classication example in mahout, I built my model as follows:

Build model:

```
./mahout trainlogistic --input donut.csv --output ./model --target color --categories 2 --predictors x y a b c --types numeric --features 20 --passes 100 --rate 10
```

I evaluate the model like this:

```
./mahout runlogistic --input donut.csv --model model  --auc --confusion
```

The output is:

```
AUC = 0.97
confusion: [[27.0, 13.0], [0.0, 0.0]]
entropy: [[-0.4, -0.3], [-1.2, -0.7]]
```

The first command produced a model file on local disk. How can I use this model to classify new data? Is there a command for that? Or do I need to write Java code to load that model and classify that?

Answer (score 2):

```
./mahout runlogistic --input new_data.csv --model model  --auc --confusion
```

For example, I fetch ten recodes from donut.csv, and it is renamed as donut2.csv.
Then I test it as follows.

```
[double@double mahout-distribution-0.7]$ bin/mahout runlogistic --input donut2.csv  --model donut.model --auc --scores --confusion
```

The output is:

```
"target","model-output","log-likelihood"
0,0.496,-0.685284
0,0.490,-0.674055
0,0.491,-0.675162
1,0.495,-0.703361
1,0.493,-0.706289
0,0.495,-0.683275
0,0.496,-0.685282
0,0.492,-0.677191
1,0.494,-0.704222
1,0.492,-0.708679
AUC = 0.50
confusion: [[6.0, 4.0], [0.0, 0.0]]
entropy: [[-0.7, -0.4], [-0.7, -0.4]]
13/06/04 15:22:50 INFO driver.MahoutDriver: Program took 1402 ms (Minutes: 0.023366666666666668)
```

Comment: Thanks lucktroy. How does this output is read ? , what does target, model-output and log-likelihood columns mean ?